# How do you automap database schema for a set of entities

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

My database has multiple schemas, the fluent nhibernate faq states that you can specify schema for the entire database, or per entity. I want to specify schema per AutoPersitenceModel, can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it:

```
public class SchemaConvention : IClassConvention
{
    public void Apply(IClassInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Schema("schemaName");
    }
}


AutoPersistenceModel model = AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Whatever>();
model.Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<SchemaConvention>();
```